# Error while executing stored procedure in SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Below is my sample stored procedure. When I am executing stored procedure by passing DATE  it is showing below error.

Invalid object name 'TEMPP'

-- stored procedure

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[mystoredprocedure]
@abc DATETIME  //coming fron front-end
AS   
BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH TEMPP AS
 (  
SELECT DISTINCT(ID), NAME  
FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPDATE > @abc 
 )  
    select DP.NAME INTO xy  from DEPARTMENT DP,TEMPP TE  
    where DP.ID=TE.ID  ;

SELECT * FROM xy;
DROP xy;
END
```

where is the mistake?

Regards,

jn

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954016/multiple-select-statements-using-sql-server-2005-with-statement

Comment: I don't think so - cte is only used once.

Comment: Btw. if you rewrite the select (using @gbn suggestion) into join, does the error persist?

Comment: if this the actual code? or a versiobn you posted here?

Comment: Did you try the script in SSMS outside the procedure? It doesn't seem to contain *anything* that could produce that error. You might have missed out the offending part somehow, when posting the script here. Try then to move it back to your code, maybe it'll help to eliminate the error if not to discover what it was.

Comment: `DROP xy;` is not valid syntax. It would need to be `DROP TABLE xy;` Please post your actual code or at least verify that the code you post demonstrates the problem you are asking about. (-1)

Answer (score 0):

from books online:
The following items are not allowed in the CTE_query_definition of a recursive member:

SELECT DISTINCT
[...]

you may try this:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[mystoredprocedure]
@abc DATETIME  //coming fron front-end
AS   
BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select DP.NAME from DEPARTMENT DP
    inner join
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT(ID), NAME  
        FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPDATE > @abc
    )TE ON DP.ID=TE.ID;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is your primary key it is already `DISTINCT`, meaning that you can remove it if @ibram answer is the cause of your error. I think `xy` is meant to be a temporary table, and can't see any use for it.

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[mystoredprocedure]
   @abc DATETIME  //coming fron front-end
AS   
BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH TEMPP AS
(  
  SELECT ID, NAME  
  FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPDATE > @abc 
)  
SELECT DP.NAME
FROM DEPARTMENT DP 
JOIN TEMPP TE
  ON DP.ID=TE.ID  ;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally see this error if you try and reference the CTE later in the procedure. It is only valid for the statement immediately following its definition.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mystoredprocedure] @abc DATETIME
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      WITH TEMPP
           AS (SELECT DISTINCT ( name ),
                               number
               from   master..spt_values)
      select number
      INTO   xy
      from   TEMPP;

      SELECT *
      FROM   xy;

      DROP table xy;

    SELECT * FROM TEMPP /*Not Allowed: Throws this error*/
  END
```