# Multiple result-sets using WITH clause

Tags: sql, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Select Statements using SQL Server 2005 “WITH” Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954016/multiple-select-statements-using-sql-server-2005-with-statement)

There's any way to get multiple result-sets from a query using WITH clause?
I'm using MS SQL 2005.

```
;with temp as 
(
    SELECT '1' as [Sample]
)
--SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp
SELECT * FROM temp
```

This works with each select (count or *), but I need to return both result-sets from the same "temp".
Is that possible?

Comment: @JonH - Thanks, that answer my question. Overlooked this topic above, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL:

```
;with temp as 
(
    SELECT '1' as [Sample]
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM temp
```

Comment: UNION ALL only works if the columns are of the same type and number.  I think the OP was just giving a simple example of what he is trying to do.  There is really no reason to `SELECT '1' as SAMPLE`.

Comment: @JonH - It does answer the question.  If I cannot read his mind. he might want COUNT(*) or SUM(*), and I cannot assume he wants more than 1 field given the (probably) over-simplified example.

Comment: It only answers the question if the OP wanted a result set of a 1 and a count, which I highly doubt.

Comment: The real answer is - see the duplicate post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you need to re-work whatever was meant to consume this pair of result sets so that it doesn't need to know how many results are going to be returned before the results arrive. If that's not the case, I can't think of where else you'd need to retrieve the `COUNT` of the result set as well as the result set itself.

Comment: Its a pagination problem. I need a "total results available" (page independent) and a result set with the selected page data only. My real query involves two more CTE to solve the pagination itself, but I removed them because I don't think they are important to the question.