# SQL Server stored procedure - refactoring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure with `parameter1` and `parameter2`

Inside the stored procedure, I am creating a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].#Temp    
(
[Item_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Item] [nvarchar](255) NULL,    
[FIELD_1] [float] NULL, 
[FIELD_2] [float] NULL

CONSTRAINT [PK___Temp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Item_ID] ASC
)
```

Then insert value to the temp table.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].#Temp(
     [Item_ID]  
    ,[Item]
    ,[FIELD_1]
    ,[FIELD_2]
)SELECT DISTINCT 
             1 
            ,'Item Description'
            ,(SELECT Field_Name FROM NewTable
              WHERE Item_type = 'Middle'  
              AND param1 = @Parameter1  
              AND param2 = @Parameter2
              AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
              AND Entity_Type = 'Entity1'
              )

            ,(SELECT Field_Name FROM NewTable
              WHERE Sch_type = 'High'  
              AND param1 = @Parameter1  
              AND param2 = @Parameter2
              AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
              AND Entity_Type = 'Entity1'
              )

INSERT INTO [dbo].#Temp(
     [Item_ID]  
    ,[Item]
    ,[FIELD_1]
    ,[FIELD_2]
)SELECT DISTINCT 
             2 
            ,'Another Item Description'
            ,(SELECT Field_Name FROM NewTable
              WHERE Item_type = 'Middle'  
              AND param1 = @Parameter1  
              AND param2 = @Parameter2
              AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
              AND Entity_Type = 'Entity2'
              )

            ,(SELECT Field_Name FROM NewTable
              WHERE Sch_type = 'High'  
              AND param1 = @Parameter1  
              AND param2 = @Parameter2
              AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
              AND Entity_Type = 'Entity2'
              )
```

so on and so forth. Then select the value from temp table and drop the temp table.

I haven't used UDF and wondering whether this could be refactored to be simple using UDF. any example and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of trips to the table are important to consider. For example, you can refactor the existing query to reduce the number of trips from 4 to 2:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].#Temp(
     [Item_ID]  
    ,[Item]
    ,[FIELD_1]
    ,[FIELD_2]
)
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            1 AS Item_ID
            ,'Item Description' AS Item
            ,CASE WHEN Item_type = 'Middle' THEN Field_Name ELSE NULL END AS Field_1
            ,CASE WHEN Sch_type = 'High' THEN Field_Name ELSE NULL END AS Field2
        FROM NewTable
        WHERE 
            param1 = @Parameter1  
            AND param2 = @Parameter2
            AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
            AND Entity_Type = 'Entity1'
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            2 AS Item_ID
            ,'Another Item Description' AS Item
            ,CASE WHEN Item_type = 'Middle' THEN Field_Name ELSE NULL END AS Field_1
            ,CASE WHEN Sch_type = 'High' THEN Field_Name ELSE NULL END AS Field2
        FROM NewTable
        WHERE 
            param1 = @Parameter1  
            AND param2 = @Parameter2
            AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
            AND Entity_Type = 'Entity2'
```

Or you could create a function with similar logic:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetStaff1FieldNames ( @param1 INT, @param2 INT, @Entity_Type VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN

    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Item_type  = 'Middle' THEN Field_Name ELSE NULL END AS Field_1,
        CASE WHEN Sch_type = 'High' THEN Field_Name ELSE NULL END AS Field_2
    FROM NewTable
    WHERE 
        param1 = @Parameter1 AND  
        param2 = @Parameter2 AND
        Entity_Type = @Entity_Type AND
        STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
    GO
```

Then call it like this:

```
SELECT
    1 
    ,'Item Description'
    ,Field_1
    ,Field_2
FROM dbo.GetStaff1FieldNames (@param1, @param2, 'Entity1')
UNION
SELECT
    2 
    ,'Another Item Description'
    ,Field_1
    ,Field_2
FROM dbo.GetStaff1FieldNames (@param1, @param2, 'Entity2')
```

There are possibly ways to retrieve everything with one trip to the table, but I would need some more context about the data to refactor further.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [Common Table (or "WITH") Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.90).aspx) for your select? Then you can get rid of the temporary table entirely.

```
WITH  Fields ( ID, Desc, MidField, HighField ) AS
      (
         SELECT DISTINCT 
                1 
              , 'Item Description'
              , (SELECT Field_Name FROM NewTable
                 WHERE Item_type = 'Middle'  
                 AND param1 = @Parameter1  
                 AND param2 = @Parameter2
                 AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
                 AND Entity_Type = 'Entity1'
                )
              , (SELECT Field_Name FROM NewTable
                 WHERE Sch_type = 'High'  
                 AND param1 = @Parameter1  
                 AND param2 = @Parameter2
                 AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
                 AND Entity_Type = 'Entity1'
                 )
         UNION
         SELECT DISTINCT 
                2 
              , 'Another Item Description'
              , (SELECT Field_Name FROM NewTable
                 WHERE Item_type = 'Middle'  
                 AND param1 = @Parameter1  
                 AND param2 = @Parameter2
                 AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
                 AND Entity_Type = 'Entity2'
                )
              , (SELECT Field_Name FROM NewTable
                 WHERE Sch_type = 'High'  
                 AND param1 = @Parameter1  
                 AND param2 = @Parameter2
                 AND STAFF_Type = 'Staff1'
                 AND Entity_Type = 'Entity2'
                )
      )
SELECT *
FROM   Fields
WHERE  MidField = 'XYZ'
```

Note that the CTE is only available to the first select statement. You [cannot perform multiple select statements against a CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954016/multiple-select-statements-using-sql-server-2005-with-statement), though you *can* have multiple CTE's for a single select statement:

```
WITH TempA ( Columns ) AS ( SELECT * FROM TableA )
   , TempB ( Columns ) AS ( SELECT * FROM TableB )
   , TempC ( Columns ) AS ( SELECT * FROM TempA, TempB )
SELECT * FROM TempC WHERE Columns = 1
```

Comment: Why on earth don't people look to CTE's when faced with an issue? They solve so much.