# SQL mutliple count

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Could you explain how I get this particular table result?

My 4 queries to individually get each column separately are also below.

I am not sure on method here do I nest the last 3 queries into the first or do I use a union between the queries.

Bearing in mind that the information in each one doesn't really match I assume Union or Union All isn't going to be useful.

Would a derived table be a better method. Sorry my SQL skills are fairly basic.

I need to also retain the ability to 'tweak' the where clauses as my admin decides to exclude certain records later (you IT folks will be used to that!)

Some the ability to alter the where clauses would be good in a solution.

Just to make it more annoying for ya ;-)

Query table would need to look a little like this

```
Company Department  Total_B Total_R Total_Ret   RushJobs
ACME    LSD     2   100     24      3
```

The four queries (that work separately to get each column above are here ( I have left in the respective Group By and where clauses incidentally I_Department does map to just Department in the case of 2nd query.

```
-- Total B count query from B
Select  Company,Department, count(*) as Total_B  from B
Group by Company,Department
Order BY Company;

--Select h count from h table
    Select count(*) as Total_R, I_Department from H
    where  L ='re-box' 
    Group By IDepartment

-- Select r count 
    Select Company,Department,Count (B_Number) AS Total_Ret
    from P Inner Join B ON P.Record_Number = B.B_Number
    where P.Request_Date > = 'SOMEDATE' and P.Request_Date < = 'SOMEDATERANGE'
    Group By Company,Department

-- Select Rush Jobs
    Select Company,Department,Count (*) as RushJobs 
    from Res
    Inner Join B on Res.Item_Number = B.B_Number 
    where Res.Setup_Date >= 'Somedate' and Res.Setup_Date<= 'somedaterange' 
    and Res.Res_Priority = '1'
     Group By Company,Department
```

So final table

```
<table><TBODY>
<TR>
<TH>Company</TH>
<TH>Department</TH>
<TH>Total_B</TH>
<TH>Total_R </TH>
<TH>Total_Ret</TH>
<TH>RushJobs</TH></TR>
<TR>
<TD>ACME</TD>
<TD>LSD</TD>
<TD>100</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>1</TD></TR></TBODY></table>
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Also, you should read this article as your first query is using a very old join style. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: How does H Relate to B?  I see no comapny on H but I do see department... so would Total_R repeat for each comapny in B?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a Common table expression (CTE) aka with statement..

This allows each query to continue to be independent allowing you to easily twerk (I was going to correct that typo but it was just too funny) the where clauses for each and combines the results in the end returning 1 record with 4 columns.

```
-- Total B count query from B
With B as (
Select  Company,Department, count(*) as Total_B  from B
Group by Company,Department
Order BY Company),

H as (
--Select h count from h table
Select count(*) as Total_R, I_Department from H
where  L ='re-box' 
Group By IDepartment),

R as (-- Select r count 
Select Company,Department,Count (B_Number) AS Total_Ret
from P Inner Join B ON P.Record_Number = B.B_Number
where P.Request_Date > = 'SOMEDATE' and P.Request_Date < = 'SOMEDATERANGE'
Group By Company,Department),

RushJobs as (-- Select Rush Jobs
Select Company,Department,Count (*) as RushJobs 
from Res
Inner Join B on Res.Item_Number = B.B_Number 
where Res.Setup_Date >= 'Somedate' and Res.Setup_Date<= 'somedaterange' 
and Res.Res_Priority = '1'
Group By Company,Department)

SELECT coalesce(B.Company, R.Company, RJ.Company)
     , coalesce(B.Department,R.Department, Rj.Department)
     , B.Total_B, H.Total_R, R.Total_Ret, RJ.RushJobs
FROM
FULL OUTER JOIN  H
   on B.Company = H.Company
FULL OUTER JOIN  R
   on B.company = R.Company
  and B.Department = R.Department
FULL OUTER JOIN  RushJobs RJ
   on H.company = RJ.Company
  and H.Department = RJ.Department
```

Comment: Upon further review, you're not just returning counts so we'd have to make those full outer joins instead of cross joins joining on company and department it seems  (though H doesn't seem to have a company)  and we may have to coalesce the names as we don't know which comapny departments will exist in each join...

Comment: Thanks xQbert I forgot to mention this is sql 2000 so no 'WITH' I believe.

Comment: Was With added on SQL 2005? I don't know

Comment: Augh... It was tagged as SQL 2008 so I assumed...  Instead of with you could create each as a "VIEW" and then 1 view tying them all together.  It's how I would have done it in 2000. and yes it was added in 2005 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954016/multiple-select-statements-using-sql-server-2005-with-statement

Comment: Sorry that was my fault I didn't spot a tag for the old stuff so I just used sql 2008 I keep dreaming that the database 'IS' !! It never happens though it stays as 2000.

Comment: Would I be able to join the 4 views using just Union or would I still need to form Select queries between them

Comment: If you used a union you'd have multiple lines for the same dept/company.  You have to join them to get the data on the same line (or I suppose, you could use union and select max for teach total grouping by the company/department.  But without understanding how "H" ties in, I really can't be confident.)

Comment: Hi xQbert, That gives me something to work on thanks. I will mess with views and see if I can post back if I get stuck. I guess I could combine the 4 views with a store procedure as well and pass in some where clauses there.